# VMMap reports ~100 GB allocations

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, virtual, vmmap

I have an application, I am afraid that there is a memory leak.
Investigating it with VMMAP I see that most of allocation are reserved memory. It should not influence on performance....?
Still the question is - what could be the reason for such amount of reserved memory (how can I investigate it?)Can it influence a performance at some stage?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Microsoft documentation page can explain what reserved memory means - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/page-state:

> **Reserved**
>
> The page has been reserved for future use. The range of addresses
> cannot be used by other allocation functions. The page is not
> accessible and has no physical storage associated with it. It is
> available to be committed.
>
> A process can use the VirtualAlloc or VirtualAllocEx function to
> reserve pages of its address space and later to commit the reserved
> pages. It can use VirtualFree or VirtualFreeEx to decommit committed
> pages and return them to the reserved state.

You can safely reserve large amount of memory, without any issues (in x64 build, which looks like the case for you)

I successfully reserved 30000 gb of memory with next code

```
#include "Windows.h"

int main()
{
    static const size_t allocationSize = 512 * 1024 * 1024;
    size_t allocated = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        void* data = ::VirtualAlloc(NULL, allocationSize, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
        if (data == nullptr)
        {
            HRESULT hr = GetLastError();
            ::DebugBreak();
        }
        allocated += allocationSize;
    }
}
```